# как golang web приложение запустить в IIS?

Tags: golang, iis, iis-7

Как веб приложение, написанное на Go, можно развернуть на windows IIS?

я написал такой код для теста

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/fcgi"
)

func handler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(res, "Hello World!")
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    fcgi.Serve(nil, nil)
}
```

как его правильно скомпилировать и настроить в IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Скомпилировать просто - выполните комманду 'go install' в коммандной строке в директории проекта. В IIS-е нужно добавить FastCgiModule (если его еще нет), и смапить путь который будет вводиться в браузере на exe-шник, который находится в GOPATH/bin.
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis
http://www.dav-muz.net/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-go-and-fastcgi/